# Black background when pushed from tableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a tab view controller which contains a tableview controller. when you press a table row it opens another tableviewcontroller (like a detailtableviewcontroller).... I have a navigation button like "add" or "+" on the top right hand side. I want to load a view controller when the + button is pressed, but every time its pressed the view controller is just a black background

```
AddSeasonViewController *stvc = [[AddSeasonViewController alloc] init];
//[self presentModalViewController:stvc animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:stvc animated:YES];

[stvc release];
```

The above code is an excerpt from the detailTableViewController

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: It seems there is nothing added to this view controller. Just for fun, set the background color to green (self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]); or something to check if this is the right viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are not initializing the viewController properly

```
AddSeasonViewController *viewController = [[AddSeasonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddSeasonViewController" bundle:nil];
```

> -->if you have a UINavigationController assigned in the UItabBarController, you can use this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

> -->I think in your case you are simply adding a viewController to the UITabBarController, then pushViewController will not work

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
  [stvc release];
```

Comment: I set the background color to black like Retterdesdialogs suggested, the view is now green however, i've done what you said re "AddSeasonViewController *viewController = [[AddSeasonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddSeasonViewController" bundle:nil];"

but i got an error 

"terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException" reason, Could not load NIB in bundle...... AddSeasonViewController

Comment: I've actually fixed it.... i believe the problem was within storyboard, i created a seperate XIB for it (indepenant from the storyboard) and it's working now, thank you very much for your help !